# Webpack web-workers loader not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-worker, webpack-dev-server

I'm building an app using webpack and I'm trying to add some web workers, I'm using a built-in plugin to load them, but I followed the example [here](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/web-worker), the official repository, and I couldn't make it work.
My webpack.dev.js looks like this:

```
import webpack              from 'webpack';
import assign               from 'object-assign';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';

import prodCfg              from './webpack.prod.config.js';

var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var DEBUG = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? true : false;
var styles = 'css!less';

Object.assign = assign;

export default function (app) {
  const config = Object.assign(prodCfg, {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-inline-source-map',
    entry:  
     [
      'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
      './client',
      'styles/main.less'
    ],
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test:    /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader:  'babel',
          query:   {
            plugins: [
              [
                'react-transform', {
                transforms: [{
                  transform: 'react-transform-hmr',
                  imports:   ['react'],
                  locals:    ['module']
                }]
              }
              ]
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loader: DEBUG ? 'style!' + styles : ExtractTextPlugin.extract(styles)
        },
        { 
          test: /\.less$/, 
          loader: DEBUG ? 'style!' + styles : ExtractTextPlugin.extract(styles)
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
      new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css", {allChunks: true })
    ],
    worker: {
      output: {
        filename: "hash.worker.js",
        chunkFilename: "[id].hash.worker.js"
      }
    }
  });

  const compiler = webpack(config);

  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {noInfo: true, publicPath: config.output.publicPath}));
  app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
}
```

and when I try to load the file I try it like this:

```
var Worker = require("worker!worker.js");
```

It would never find the file, the only files exported by webpack are bundle.js and style.css, it looks like the worker loader is not loading anything at all, or maybe I just don't understand the logic behind the loader, anyway there isn't much documentation about this nor implemented examples. So I hope someone had implemented this successfully and can shed some light on my problem.

Any help would be very welcomed! Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You need to put it in the loaders section -

in your webpack config, something like

```
const config = Object.assign(prodCfg, {
...
module: {
  loaders: [
  ...
  { 
      test: /\.less$/, 
      loader: DEBUG ? 'style!' + styles : ExtractTextPlugin.extract(styles)
  },
  { 
      test: /worker\.js$/,
      loader: 'worker'
  }
...
```

then you should see it as a separate output of webpack.

Hope it helps

Comment: Helped me a lot, thanks!
In addition, I needed to add 'library.worker.js' entry to webpack configuration. In my case, worker is used from external library, and without 'entry' webpack doesn't generate worker file (webpack doesn't know it used at all).

Comment: Just in case a complete beginner to webpack, like me, comes across this, if you load worker-loader in the loader section you no longer need to load it in the require. So instead of `require("worker!worker.js")`, you would just need `require("worker.js")`.
Doing both won't work and you won't see any error messages.

Answer (score 2):

In the example you linked to, your line here:

```
var Worker = require("worker!worker.js");
```

Looks like this:

```
var Worker = require("worker!./worker");
```

Note that there is a `./` to indicate a relative path. Also, you do not need the `.js` when calling `require` on another file.

Do you have a file called `worker.js` relative to your shared code?

Comment: Hi Cymen, thank you for you quick answer. Yes I tried the notation you suggest: var Worker = require("worker!./worker"); But the issue is that the file doesn't exist at all in the export result from webpack, so there's no way the file will be found

Comment: @XaviBonell So in your linked example, they have a webpack configuration that emits a bundle named `worker` -- I think you may need to configure webpack to emit your regular bundle and a `worker` bundle. See https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/web-worker -- this is not at all obvious.

Comment: thanks again,  the link you provided is the same that I linked on my question, so that is exactly what I'm trying to do, generate a regular bundle and a worker one, but I can't really do it, should be easy, right? Well it is not. Anyway I opened a thread with the same question in their GitHub repository, hopefully they will point me to the right direction! [link](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2138)

Comment: @XaviBonell Ah! Sorry, I missed that. Hopefully, you get your answer on github and can post here and accept your own answer (and it'll help out everyone else who is trying to figure this out too).

Comment: @XaviBonell One other thing to try is the chat app Discord -- there is a #webpack channel that is active. It's a free app. Meant for gaming but bunch of people using it for software development (slack maxes out at like 10k users or something while Discord doesn't).

Comment: @XaviBonell I forgot to link to the actual Discord server: http://www.reactiflux.com/